# How to run some code only when the rails console starts, kind of like an rc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Is there a way to execute some code that is run only when the console starts? Kind of like an rc file (`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.)? I find myself always doing certain things a lot.

For example, where would I put this

```
u = User.find_by_username('my_console_user')
```

so that `u` is available in `rails console`?

I have resorted to this, the use of `$` as global variable declaration, and the use of the obscure `console do`. I assume there is something more elegant somehow...

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    #this is only executed in the console, also doens't seem to be documented anywhere but here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3139
    console do
      $u1 = User.find_by_username('user1')
      $u2  = User.find_by_username('user2')
    end

  end
```

Comment: Include this in an initializer

Comment: Nutshell: the `~/.irbrc` file contains code that (a) checks to see that we're not in `~`, and if not, looks for an `.irbrc` file in the current directory, and loads it if there is. I'm ambivalent about this being a good idea, and often just have a script that starts up a session, loading a file during startup.

Comment: In the console just type: `load 'foo.rb'` and the contents of the `foo.rb` will be executed. Put there all your needed code.

Comment: @apneadiving: which bit? THe whole thing?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `irb`, just add a method in `~/.irbrc` (create one if does not exist):

```
def find_by_username(username)
  User.find_by_username('my_console_user')
end
```

Or add to `~/.pryrc` if you use `pry-rails`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What it we want this to be part of the project itself? so that other developers can have the benefit?

Comment: Commit the irbrc / pryrc to the version control.

Comment: And then leave instructions for the user to copy it to their home folder?

Comment: When they clone your repository will also clone irbrc / pryrc, then it will work.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible for a repo to clone files to places outside of its working directory? Or does irb look for the presence of .irbrc in the current working directory?

Comment: Confusion here boils down to: Does have to be `~/.irbrc` (in user home) or just `.irbrc` (in the current or project directory)?

Comment: I believe it needs to be in the home directory. If not, then you need a generic script script in the home directory that checks for the existence of another `.irbrc` in the CWD and executes that. Either way, not so good if you're in a team. In my opinion the `console do ... end` method is better as it encapsulates the code within the repository.